# How to determine whether I need to restart due to upgrades on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, update

When I use apt to update my system (e.g. run `sudo aptitude full-upgrade`) it sometimes installs updates that require reboots. This applies esp. for kernel (security) updates.

I can sometimes see this in the ssh login message.  I'm wondering how (else) I may determine whether the system needs a reboot due to these updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MOTD "restart required" text is generated by `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required`, which checks for the existence of and pulls text from `/var/run/reboot-required`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# helper for update-motd

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        cat /var/run/reboot-required
fi
```